# File reading program hangs at end of while loop (linux c)

Tags: c, linux, io

sorry for the trivial question. I'm reading a file character by character. It appears to work up until the final run (EOF), where for some reason the program hangs.

The final line of the while loop "Done outer loop, in is 0" is printed, but 
for some reason the loop does not exit even though the condition is "(in != '0')". The line "Finished parsing events" doesn't print and the program stops and is unresponsive.

```
char in = '1';
FILE *fid = fopen(filename, "r");
while (in != '0') {
    printf("Start of loop, in is %c\r\n", in);
    if ((in = fgetc(fid)) == EOF) 
        in = '0';

    /* Large block that does stuff depending on the value of in*/

    printf("Done outer loop, in is %c\r\n", in);

}

fclose(fid);
printf("Finished parsing events");
//fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Read the docs. `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reasons.

Comment: @user3074 seeing your comment under the answer, please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. I notice you don't have `newline` after the final print, and commented out the `fflush`.

Comment: So, does *exactly* what you have here, with the "Large block that does stuff depending on the value of in" *completely commented out*, still produce the same appearance of a hang?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
char in = '1';
```

To:

```
int in = '1';
```

First of all the return type of `fgetc` function is `int`. When you reach the end of file `EOF` is returned (which is likely to be `-1`, I assume that it's equal to `-1`). Then `-1` is stored in the `in` variable, whose type is `char`. It's not defined in standard is `char` signed or not, in your case it seems to be unsigned, so `in` becomes `255`. Then `in` is promoted to `int` type to be compared with `EOF`, but `255 != -1` of course, so you're in the infinite cycle.

Comment: I see. Similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057259/fgetc-checking-eof).

Comment: Very common indeed, I see it frequently (once a week or so, depending on how close to the end of a semester the school year is).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This doesn't appear to have any effect on the output. If it were looping infinitely, wouldn't the lines ("Start of loop...") and ("End of loop...") also repeat infinitely? This is not the case here.

Comment: @user3074 Generally speaking lines should repeat infinitely. But it may depends on the code which is described as "Large block..."

Comment: @user3074 In any case you can check your program with debugger before and after aforementioned fix.

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice remark about the dependence between certain types of questions and school semesters :)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the code you post, and the answers you have received about the use of `fgetc(3)`, the code you have posted should not hang.  Let's see what happens:

`fgetc(3)` returns `int` `-1` value (as an `int`, as normally is so defined the constant `EOF`) to differentiate the 256 possibilities for an 8 bit `char`, plus one more, for the `EOF` condition (which is not a data value coming from the stream) and it is converted to a `char` (making  `EOF` simply an alias of some valid input). In you case, you have assimilated that condition to one of the values of the `char` type, by error.

But that doesn't normally makes the program to hang (it doesn't even define Undefined Behaviour, except for the fact that we actually don't know which `char` value will be used as an alias of the `EOF` condition).  The program will have then **two conditions for `break`ing the loop** (as you have masked one).  The first being the real `EOF` condition, and the second is receiving from the input stream actually the `char` that `EOF` is being converted to when you input it.

As somebody points in the comments.  **The problem must be in the large, commented block**, you have deliverately hidden.  Even if the `printf(3)` you execute after it does, and the outer of the block doesn't, you can have errors in the hidden block, that manifest only when leaving it, and make the error apparent to be in the loop test you make at the beginning of the code block.

Changing the `char in = '1';` to `int in = '1';` is a good choice to eliminate the problem of a spureous `break`s, but your hanging problem is not there... you have to post the hidden block to get more feedback.

### IMPORTANT NOTE

Try to get used to write complete failing examples... Don't edit the code just to post it, without testing that it continues failing (as yours doesn't, I demonstrate that below), and you will not get this kind of answers (that seem more a flame than a try to help you).  The code you posted, **at least must be edited to make it runnable**, as you have pasted only a snippet of code that, as such, is even not compilable.  Some such example, should be like the one I post below, but, as it doesn't fail, cannot be used to fix your problem.  Right?

```
#include <stdio.h>             /* line added to make runnable */
#define filename "test.txt"    /* line added to make runnable */
int main()                     /* line added to make runnable */
{                              /* line added to make runnable */
    char in = '1';
    FILE *fid = fopen(filename, "r");
    while (in != '0') {
        printf("Start of loop, in is %c\r\n", in);
        if ((in = fgetc(fid)) == EOF) 
            in = '0';

        /* Large block that does stuff depending on the value of in*/

        printf("Done outer loop, in is %c\r\n", in);

    }

    fclose(fid);
    printf("Finished parsing events");
    //fflush(stdout);
}                              /* line added to make runnable */
```

It runs as shown below (without any hung) (please, note that the `sed(1)` command is used to add the four spaces needed to embed the output here as
output text, you must not use it at home for testing purposes):

```
$ pru8 | sed -e 's/^/    /'
Start of loop, in is 1
Done outer loop, in is p
Start of loop, in is p
Done outer loop, in is s
Start of loop, in is s
Done outer loop, in is d

[...] <--- a lot more of repeating lines like the ones posted above.

Start of loop, in is  
Done outer loop, in is 

Start of loop, in is 

Done outer loop, in is 0
Finished parsing events
$ _
```

and no hung.